# launch php script from android application and get graph output

Tags: php, android, linux

I want to launch a php script located on my linux webserver (/var/www) from android application and get its output (ploted graph).This is my php script

```
<?php
 $client = new Mosquitto\Client();
$client->onConnect('connect');
$client->onDisconnect('disconnect');
 $client->onSubscribe('subscribe');
$client->onMessage('message');
$client->connect("localhost", 8080, 60);
$client->subscribe('+/#', 1);
  while (true) {
    $client->loop();
    sleep(2);
  }

  $client->disconnect();
 unset($client);

  function connect($r) {
    echo "I got code {$r}\n";
  }

function subscribe() {
    echo "Subscribed to a topic\n";
    exec("Rscript script1.R");
 }

 function message($message) {
   printf("\nGot a message on topic %s with payload:%s", 
            $message->topic, $message->payload);
    $dbusername = "root";  // enter database username, I used "arduino" in step 2.2
$dbpassword = "qwertyazerty";  // enter database password, I used "arduinotest" in step 2.2
$server = "localhost:8008"; 

    $dbconnect = mysql_connect($server, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
$dbselect = mysql_select_db("iotdatas",$dbconnect);

 if ($message->topic == "home/temperature"){

$tempinter = $message->payload;

 $sql = "INSERT INTO iotdatas.iotDataInter (internetemp) VALUES ('".$tempinter."')";   
echo $sql; 

mysql_query($sql);
  }

    if ($message->topic == "a020a61af8a0/temperature"){

$tempext = $message->payload;

 $sql1 = "INSERT INTO iotdatas.iotDataExter (externetemp) VALUES ('".$tempext."')";   
echo $sql1; 

// Execute SQL statement

mysql_query($sql1);


   }

$sql2= "SELECT externetemp from iotdatas.iotDataExter";


 $sql2;
$req2=mysql_query($sql2);
while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($req2)){
    $arr1 = $row['externetemp'];
echo $arr1;

}

 $sql3= "SELECT internetemp from iotdatas.iotDataInter";

 $sql3;
$req3= mysql_query($sql3);
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($req3)){
$arr2 = $row['internetemp'];
echo $arr2;

 }



   $size1= "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM iotdatas.iotDataExter";
   $rs1 = mysql_query($size1);

  $size2="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM iotdatas.iotDataInter";
    $rs2 = mysql_query($size2);

   }

  exec("Rscript script1.R");

  function disconnect() {
    echo "Disconnected cleanly\n";
       }
```

and this is my android code but I find that the script didn't execute.

```
 public class lunchScript extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;

        try {
            URL url;
            url = new URL(params[0]);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                Log.i("res ",conn.toString());
                Log.i("res1 ",is.toString());

            } else {
                InputStream err = conn.getErrorStream();
            }
            return "Done";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Stop using the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: @AlexHowansky I don't think the problem was from mysql because I execute my script from the server side and it work perfectly.

Comment: My comment was not meant to address the problem you're having, it was simply meant to let you know that your code is outdated.